# Source of least square estimator of Poisson parameter

Tags: poisson-distribution, least-squares, estimators

I have $X \sim \text{Poisson}(\theta)$

I need to see how least square estimator of $\theta$ is obtained. Is there anything online showing that?

Comment: This seems to be essentially the same question as [this one](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/122153/least-squares-estimation-of-poisson-parameter)... in the same class, perhaps?

Comment: I did see this one, but it did not really help me. What I want is the proof of the least square estimator of $\theta$